How to modify jetty response body if the request isAsyncSupported?
currently I'm using a Filter to do so, but it doesn't work.
Below is my Filter code:
public class ProcessHandlerFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        ContentCapturingResponseWrapper capturingResponseWrapper = new ContentCapturingResponseWrapper(resp);
        chain.doFilter(request, capturingResponseWrapper);
        
        if (request.isAsyncSupported() && request.isAsyncStarted()) {
            request.getAsyncContext().addListener(new AsyncListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                    log.info("====output is {} after request complete", response.getOutputStream());
                    handleFilter(response, capturingResponseWrapper);
                }

                @Override
                public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                    log.warn("Http request {} async context timeout.", request);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                    log.warn("Http request {} async context error.", request, asyncEvent.getThrowable());
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) {}
            });
        } else {
            handleFilter(response, capturingResponseWrapper);
        }
    }

    private void handleFilter(ServletResponse response,
                              ContentCapturingResponseWrapper capturingResponseWrapper) throws IOException {
        byte[] data = capturingResponseWrapper.getContent();
        // do filter logic
        // xxx
        log.info("====get response {}", new String(data));
        log.info("====output is {}", response.getOutputStream());
        ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        response.getOutputStream().write(data);
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
}

and below is the capturingResponseWrapper code:
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContentCapturingResponseWrapper.class);
    private ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    public ContentCapturingResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ServletOutputStream() {
            public boolean isReady() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener) {

            }

            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                output.write(b);
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
               output.write(b, off, len);
            }
        };
    }

    public byte[] getContent() {
        return output.toByteArray();
    }


and the http request error is insufficient content written, error logs contains:
2024-12-05T00:31:28,691+0000 [test-web-75-7] INFO  io.example.com.ProcessHandlerFilter - ====output is HttpOutput@588c8d5a{s=CLOSED,api=BLOCKING,sc=false,e=null} after request complete
2024-12-05T00:31:28,691+0000 [test-web-75-7] INFO  io.example.com.ProcessHandlerFilter - ====get response ["public","temp"]
2024-12-05T00:31:28,691+0000 [test-web-75-7] INFO  io.example.com.ProcessHandlerFilter - ====output is HttpOutput@588c8d5a{s=CLOSED,api=BLOCKING,sc=false,e=null}
2024-12-05T00:31:28,691+0000 [test-web-75-7] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed while invoking onComplete listener io.example.com.ProcessHandlerFilter$1@62114af8

Based on the logs, I think the error reason is that the outputStream of original response is closed when the code goes into the onComplete method, and then I cannot write to it, is there any other way to modify the response for an async request?
